# ¿Cómo hago para que AJAX me diga en tiempo real si un usuario existe (de un array php)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Soy nuevo por aquí.. Estoy empezando con AJAX y no se muy bien como funciona todavía. Mi codigo es un formulario que al escribir un correo me tiene que decir en tiempo real si ya existe o no existe (como un sistema de registro de usuario, algo así). Los nombres de correos están en un array en PHP.

El tema esta en que mediante ajax siempre me dice que no existe, pero si coloco para darle enter al php si que me dice correctamente si existe o no.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
        function compruebaCorreo() 
            peticion.onreadystatechange = function () { 
                if (peticion.readyState == 4 && peticion.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = peticion.responseText;
                    }
            };

            peticion.open("POST", "comprueba.php", true); 

            var correo = "correo=" +document.getElementById("correoo").value ;
            peticion.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-wwwform-urlencoded");
            peticion.send(correo);
            }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="comprueba.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text"  id="correoo" name="correo" onkeyup="compruebaCorreo(this)";>
    </form>
    <div id="caja"></div>
</body>
```

```
<?php
$correo = isset( $_POST['correo']);



    if(compruebaCorreo($correo)){
        echo "El usuario EXISTE";
    } else {
        echo "El usuario no existe";
    }

function compruebaCorreo($correo){
    $arrayCorreos = array ('luis@terra.es','mario@ono.com','sara@yahoo.es','ana@gmail.com');
    $encontrado = false;
    foreach($arrayCorreos as $valor){
        if($valor==$correo){
            $encontrado=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $encontrado;
}
```

?>

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask], editar y colocar un título que sea descriptivo pues poner *inicios en ....* no da mucha idea del problema

Comment: Hola! Pido disculpas! Es mi primera vez por aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
$correo = isset( $_POST['correo']);
```

Estas buscando la variable `$correo` dentro del array, pero `isset()` retorna `true` o `false`.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
<?php
if(isset( $_POST['correo'])) {
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];

    if(compruebaCorreo($correo)){
        echo "El usuario EXISTE";
    } else {
        echo "El usuario no existe";
    }

  function compruebaCorreo($correo){
    $arrayCorreos = array ('luis@terra.es','mario@ono.com','sara@yahoo.es','ana@gmail.com');
    $encontrado = false;
    foreach($arrayCorreos as $valor){
        if($valor==$correo){
            $encontrado=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $encontrado;
  }
} else {
  echo "correo vacio"
}
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta! Aun así he probado tu código y siempre muestra "correo vacío", aunque escriba uno de los correos del array. Es lo mismo que me pasaba antes, siempre mostraba que el usuario no existe.